# SSRS 2005 Multiple formats in a single textbox

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Is it possible to have multiple formatting of a text string within a single textbox in SSRS 2005?

example:

The **quick** *brown* **fox jumped** over the lazy *brown* dog.

possible setting font colors as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Nope***... SSRS2005 does not support this feature.  However, ***it is available in SSRS2008***.

**Potential Workaround**: 
For one project we were presented with needing to change the format on the middle name of a name field.  We were able to place 3 textboxes on the report and use some substring and trim functions to get the text we wanted in each textbox.

I'm not sure how common the text elements are that you're working with, but this may be something that you can attempt.  If there is any chance that the data is not consistent, I would avoid doing this...

Answer (score 1):

Like Yadyn, I have never seen anything that would suggest this were possible within the confines of a single textbox.

SSRS is notorious for not being the most intuitive, forgiving, or customizable.

Comment: Notorious? I found it's great in intuition. Not best in customization. Microsoft doesn't normally do it right until version 3.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  no.

---

If there is, I haven't been able to figure it out.  We tasked an intern once as part of a larger task in SSRS 2005 to figure out if it was possible.  He came back saying it wasn't possible.  I never found anything in my time working with it either, since.

I'd love to hear otherwise from someone.